# How to count requests to second level domains if I have a DB table with full domain names?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have table `table1`with columns `domain`, `request_time`. Here is example of the records (I ignored `request_time` since it is not important for this question).

```
Domain
--------------------
abc.example1.com
def.example1.com
def.example1.com
def.example1.com
yyy.example2.com
zzz.example3.com
ghi.example1.com
zzz.example3.com
def.example1.com
yyy.example2.com
zzz.example3.com
def.example1.com
ghi.example1.com
zzz.example3.com
yyy.example2.com
yyy.example2.com
def.example1.com
yyy.example2.com
zzz.example3.com
def.example1.com
ghi.example1.com
def.example1.com
zzz.example3.com
def.example1.com
yyy.example2.com
zzz.example3.com
yyy.example2.com
abc.example1.com
```

I'm using this query to COUNT requests for each domain:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Domain, COUNT(*) AS REQUESTS_COUNT
FROM table1
GROUP BY Domain
ORDER BY REQUESTS_COUNT
```

As a result I get:

```
def.example1.com    9
yyy.example2.com    7
zzz.example3.com    7
ghi.example1.com    3
abc.example1.com    2
```

**How can I get results based on second level domain name ?**

Here is example what I want to get:

```
example1.com    14
example2.com    7
example3.com    7
```

I'm using sqlite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `substr()` & `instr()` :

```
select substr(domain, instr(Domain,'.') + 1), count(*) as REQUESTS_COUNT
from table1 t1
group by substr(domain, instr(Domain,'.') + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`Substring`** and **`CharIndex`** to get the desire output, please check below query as well.

This is for **`SQL Server`** ..

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(Domain,CHARINDEX('.',domain)-1,LEN(Domain)) AS Domain_Name,Count(*) AS REQUESTS_COUNT
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY SUBSTRING(Domain,CHARINDEX('.',domain)-1,LEN(Domain))
    ORDER BY REQUESTS_COUNT
```

For **`SQLite`**..

```
SELECT SUBSTR(Domain,INSTR(domain,'.')+1,LENGTH(domain)-INSTR(domain,'.')) AS Domain_Name,Count(*) AS REQUESTS_COUNT
    FROM table1
    GROUP BY SUBSTR(Domain,INSTR(domain,'.')+1,LENGTH(domain)-INSTR(domain,'.')) 
    ORDER BY REQUESTS_COUNT
```

Comment: Thanks bro ,I thought it's SQL Server , thanks a lot for correcting me..

Comment: Thanks for answering. For SQLite it has to be `SUBSTR` instead of `SUBSTRING`.